# How to get "_getch()" to not pause c program

Tags: c, input, getch

How can I get input from the user without pausing the program? I have this program right here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf("loop\n");
        _getch();
        Sleep(80);
        
    }
}
```

How can I get it to do the while loop without pausing while still getting the input from the user?

Comment: Get rid of `<conio.h>`. Use [`ncurses` library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Also you might like Q19.1 on [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/)

Comment: Use [`_kbhit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=msvc-160) to check.

Comment: *How* doesn't `_kbhit` "change shit"?  It should return immediately with a status telling if  there's a character to be read or not. Something like `if (_kbhit()) { _getch(); }` should work well for your problem.

Answer (score -3):

I think I would add a timer in a loop in a second thread and if the user didnt apply input in a certain time, restart the getc() request.. on the first look, using 1 of my braincells it seems you are best off using another core due to the nature of the getc() and similar functions. While you should also check the code of this function to see if there are faster ways

Comment: I solved the problem. But sure thing I'll checkmark your answer

Comment: Starting another thread with a timer is overkill unless you do want a timeout response, but that wasn't asked, and even then another thread is unnecessary. The [above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561693/how-to-get-getch-to-not-pause-c-program#comment117666501_66561693) from dude is as simple as it gets.

Comment: It always depens on what you try to do and how important it is to use exactly that function..